Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null
I have Nuxt app, and a very simple handler for the contact form (using nodemailer). Locally everything is working fine, but on the server i get the next error:
{
    "url": "/api/contact",
    "statusCode": 500,
    "statusMessage": "",
    "message": "Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null",
    "stack": ""
}

And this the handler:
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    try {
        const body = await readBody(event)
        const { error } = contactSchema.validate(body)

        if (error) {
            throw new Error(`Invalid request body: ${error.message}`)
        }
        const { name, email, tel, message } = body
        const config = useRuntimeConfig()
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: config.SMTP_HOST,
            port: 587,
            secure: false,
            auth: {
                user: config.SMTP_USER,
                pass: config.SMTP_PASS,
            },
        })
    

        const mailOptions = {
            from: `Website form" <${config.SMTP_EMAIL}>`,
            to: config.SMTP_EMAIL,
            subject: `Webform - Name: ${name}`,
            html: `
        <p>Name: ${name}</p>
        <p>Phone: ${tel}</p>
        <p>Email: ${email}</p>
        <p>${message}</p>
      `,
        }

        // Send the email
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(`Error: ${error}`)
            } else {
                console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response)
            }
        })

        return { code: 200, message: 'Email sent successfully' }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        return { code: 500, message: 'Failed to send email' }
    }
})

does somebody know what could be the cause of this?

You need to debug the error on server side, it's extremely uninformative as 500, the call stack was lost. This error means that a class extends something that doesn't exist, this often occurs when a platform is wrong so builtin modules and classes don't exist, e.g. node version is wrong or node code was incorrectly bundled so it doesn't refer the respective builtins
